# Regex to iterate over an table and extract the td information inside an div using java

Tags: java, regex

Hello i know parsing HTML with regex is not efficient .But i need to do with regex i have no other option.

HTML

```
    <div class="test">
        <h2>what</h2>


        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>

        <tr>
            <th>Example                            </th>
            <td> ui                         </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Sample                            </th>
            <td>123                     </td>
        </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I tried to do it using `(?s)<div class="test">.*<td>(.*?)</td>.*</div>` it extracts only the last value can any one tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why only using Regular expression, how about some jquery??

```
$("div.test > td").each(function() { 
    var $this = $(this);
    alert( $this.text() ) 
});
```

Comment: You mixed Java and Javascript I assume?

Comment: I need it using java . If i can use JSoup lib in java it is very easy like the above one but i need to do it in regex.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operator reads as much as is possible, so the first `.*` also swallows most of the text.

Try with `.*?`. The question mark reduces this behaviour and lets `*` only take as much as necessary, not as much as possible.

Otherwise please be more specific what parts you really want and which not.

Comment: I need to extract all the values inside the td tag

Comment: You need to extract ONLY the values in TD, or the TD values all together? In the first case you can only match "<td>(.*?)</td>" and repeat that match. Would be good to have your Java code as example. But matching the whole block and not the sub-pattern seems not useful to me. Matching the individual pattern and using the repeat functions of Java regexp sounds better to me.

Comment: BTW: If you need data from a specific group, simply do two regexp in sequence. The first filtering the div, the second the content.

Comment: I need to extract all the TD values all together. I am using a tool which accepts regex. The tool is made using JAVA.